# Using tsocks to access external-networks which have only one machine accessible with public-world addressible machine

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

We have a set of machines in a datacenter. Only one of the machines is accessible from the internet-world. If we need to talk to any other machine in the datacenter we would need to login to this internet-visible machine.

We have a monitoring web-tool which monitors all the servers. For this to work I needed the browser to be in the same lan as datacenter. I made this possible by using dynamic-forwarding a port from my local machine to the world visible machine and set this port as the proxy on my browser .. this worked fine.

Now I wanted to use some command-line tools which needed to talk to all the machines in the datacenter. The only way I could make that work was to login to world-visible machine and run my commands from there.

After looking around on the web, I discovered(could be wrongly) that I can use tsocks to achieve the goal of running my command line tools on my local machine as-if they are running in the datacenter network. However, I am having trouble getting them work. I am attaching the tsocks.conf file I created

```
local = 192.168.81.0/255.255.255.0
local = 0.0.0.0/255.255.255.255

path {
     reaches = 192.168.5.0/255.255.255.0
     server = 0.0.0.0
     server_port = 8080
     server_type = 5
}
path {
     reaches = 10.125.4.0/255.255.255.0
     server = 0.0.0.0
     server_port = 8081
     server_type = 5
}
path {
     reaches = 10.110.80.0/255.255.255.0
     server = 0.0.0.0
     server_port = 8082
     server_type = 5
}
```

I have all the three server_ports mentioned above dynamically-forwarded using ssh and I am able to use each of them as a proxy for my browser with no trouble to access machines on each of the three datacenters but doing 
. tsocks -on
and pinging one of the machines does not give me any response.. It does not look like my set up is working... can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the wrong question. Everything was working fine. I was trying to ping a server in the network which was configured not to respond to pings at all. Other operations such as ssh work fine. So the proxy was setup properly. just the way I was testing was wrong.
Thanks,
Sunil.